# How to prompt the user again to enter valid values?

Tags: java

Hi we were tasked to create a program that accepts three positive integers from the user, say x, y, and i. The program will display all numbers divisible by i between x and y. Therefore, x and i must be less than y. If the user enters an invalid input, he must be prompted again by the program to enter valid values.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TrialD {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int i = 0;


        System.out.print("Enter x: ");
        x = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter y: ");
        y = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter i: ");
        i = sc.nextInt();


        if((x<y)&&(i<y)) {

            for(int c = x; c < y; c++) {
                if(c % i == 0) {
                    System.out.print(c + " ");
                }
            }
        }

            else System.out.println("Invalid Input!");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a while loop till the correct input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TrialD {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        book correct = false;

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int i = 0;

        while(!correct) {
        System.out.print("Enter x: ");
        x = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter y: ");
        y = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter i: ");
        i = sc.nextInt();


        if((x<y)&&(i<y)) {
             correct = true;
            for(int c = x; c < y; c++) {
                if(c % i == 0) {
                    System.out.print(c + " ");
                }
            }
        }

            else System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag to check if your condition is true, and repeat the scanning part.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int i = 0;

    boolean flag = false;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter x: ");
        x = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter y: ");
        y = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter i: ");
        i = sc.nextInt();


        if ((x < y) && (i < y)) {
            flag = true;
            for (int c = x; c < y; c++) {
                if (c % i == 0) {
                    System.out.print(c + " ");
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
        }

    } while (!flag);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the loop with condition that you've mentioned:

```
while(x < y && i < y) {
        System.out.print("Enter x: ");
        x = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter y: ");
        y = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter i: ");
        i = sc.nextInt();

        if (!(x < y && i < y)) {
              System.out.print("x and i must be less than y.");
        }
}
```